# mysql insert into not work

Tags: php, mysql

I want insert 4 datas into 4 fields and checked if 2 of them have not exists. (the data match `pid = '1' and sid '123')

Here is my code, I checked several times, my `mysql connect` is well, my database is right, these four fields in my `table`. but I just can not insert. there has no warning return page.

```
require ("connect.php");// this one I always test on my localhost, no proble, even require on other page, all works well
mysql_select_db("test",$database_link);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_data (uid, pid, sid, wid)  SELECT  '123456', '1', '123', '2' FROM dual WHERE not exists (SELECT pid,sid FROM user_data WHERE user_data.pid = '1' AND  user_data.sid = '123')");
```

for see clearlly:

```
INSERT INTO user_data (uid, pid, sid, wid) 
SELECT '123456', '1', '123', '2' 
FROM dual 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT pid, sid 
    FROM user_data 
    WHERE user_data.pid = '1' 
    AND user_data.sid = '123'
)
```

Error message:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'pid, sid, wid) SELECT '123456', '1', '123', '2' FROM dual WHERE not exists (SE' at line 1`

Comment: Have you used [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) to get any error message? Please show us the definition of your table, are there any indexes?

Comment: Running the insert (select in particular) from the a MySQL console shows what?

Comment: Can you show the PHP code? Are you doing any error checking?

Comment: make it mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_data (uid, pid, sid, wid)  SELECT  '123456', '1', '123', '2' FROM dual WHERE not exists (SELECT pid,sid FROM user_data WHERE user_data.pid = '1' AND  user_data.sid = '123')") or die ("Error: " . mysql_error()); and tell us what you have.

Comment: @Mido, update error message, where is the problem? near `(SE'` ? I have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: are you trying to insert rows or data? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: @Mido , I want insert `'123456', '1', '123', '2'` table `user_data` and fields `uid, pid, sid, wid`, and checked field (`pid=1` and `sid=123`) not EXISTS in table `user_data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a duplicate name problem on the tables, try to use alias :

```
INSERT INTO user_data (uid, pid, sid, wid) 
SELECT '123456', '1', '123', '2' 
FROM dual 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT NULL -- don't need to select fields in a NOT EXISTS clause
    FROM user_data u2
    WHERE u2.pid = '1' 
    AND u2.sid = '123'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Query works fine on MySQL 5.1.54.

From [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html):

> The target table of the INSERT statement may appear in the FROM clause
>   of the SELECT part of the query. (This was not possible in some older
>   versions of MySQL.) However, you cannot insert into a table and select
>   from the same table in a subquery.
>
> When selecting from and inserting into a table at the same time, MySQL
>   creates a temporary table to hold the rows from the SELECT and then
>   inserts those rows into the target table. However, it remains true
>   that you cannot use INSERT INTO t ... SELECT ... FROM t when t is a
>   TEMPORARY table, because TEMPORARY tables cannot be referred to twice
>   in the same statement (see Section C.5.7.2, “TEMPORARY Table
>   Problems”).

Could this be the reason?